# PC with Optane + Intel RST, Will Not Boot Into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid, intel

I have an identical problem to the one posted here:

[Can't boot Ubuntu because Windows 10 rewrites entire EFI partition [Solved]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved)

In short, I have managed to install ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 10 on an HP Pavilion that has Intel Optane & Intel Rapid Storage Tech (Which uses RAID). At first the ubuntu installation wizard couldn't identify the windows partition, but after I entered the command "sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda" in a live usb trial session it suddenly worked.

Now the Ubuntu is installed but the PC will not boot into it. Boot options (F9\10) do not recognize any other OS than Windos. I have tried all the options listed in the above post to no avail.

The "solution" given in the post was to disable the Intel Optane, but I paid good money for it and I would certainly like it to continue working on the Windows partition.

Has anyone encountered this problem and managed to boot into Ubuntu **without** disabling Optane from the Windows partition?

Thanks in advance!
Steve

Comment: I found unaccelerating the drive in Windows before installing Ubuntu was the safest route. After installing Ubuntu the drive could be accelerated again in Windows and left accelerated.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, can you please be a little more specific on what you did? how did you unaccelerate & accelerate? Does your PC boot into grub properly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Intel Rapid Storage Technologies had a Windows App where you define what hard drives to accelerate and how many GB of PCIe SSD assigned to each. I left half of it unassigned for Linux to use to accelerate Ubuntu's partition using EnhanceIO. Now days though I would just buy NVMe Gen 3.0 x 4 and skip Intel RST altogether.

Comment: Related: [Use Intel RST while dual-booting Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923150/use-intel-rst-while-dual-booting-ubuntu)