# Stuck at initramfs prompt AFTER removing a non existent HDD

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, initramfs

My Ubuntu installation does not boot when I remove a non relevant HDD (sda) from my system. Instead I am stuck in initramfs. However if it is connected it starts up just fine from sdb3.

- sda unallocated - the hdd required to boot for whatever reason
- sdb3 `/`
- sdb5 swap
- sdb6 `home`

It might be worth mentioning that I tried to clone sdb as is to sda using clonezilla live which failed. So sda has no partitions, but if I boot from sda grub rescue appears.

UUIDs of `blkid -l` match those of `fstab`

`initramfs-tool/conf.d/resume` points to sdb5

GRUB and initramfs were updated several times

`fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb3` was run several times from live with no errors

Any help would be appreciated since this is my main driver and the problem doesn't seem too severe.

Comment: What error do you get when you boot before you drop to the rescue shell?

Comment: The error message says: `ALERT! /dev/sdb3 does not exist. Dropping to shell!` It's pretty much the same scenario like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013927/begin-running-scripts-local-block-done-stuck-in-initramfs-on-ubuntu-17) except for the fact i can't `cryptsetup`. However my `/etc/crypttab` is empty.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong. You will have to boot and fix this from a live CD

Comment: Can you boot an older kernel?  Can you mount the encrypted partition with a live usb?

Comment: As mentioned the system boots just fine from sdb3 if sda (which is empty/unallocated) is connected to the system as well. So yes i can access the drive's content and yes i can mount it using a live usb.

Comment: Remove all references to sda (perhaps by uuid) in fstab. Is grub installed on sdb?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution for my particular problem: Apparaently cloning the existing partitions to a new hdd via clonezilla beforehand somehow mashed up my kernel boot commands - which were for some reason set to drive letters instead to UUIDs in grub

Lesson learned: always check for every parameter involved.

Thank you Panther for your time and effort.